# Hide actionButton when you change any value in any of the shiny widgets of shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the `shiny` app below in which when I press the `actionButton()` a second `actionButton()` is displayed. I want to know if it is possible when I make any change in any of the 2 `selectInput()` in the sidebar the 2nd actionButton to be hidden again.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Define UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Subset Iris Dataset"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("columns_selected", "Select Columns", choices = colnames(iris), multiple = TRUE),
    selectInput("columns_selected2", "Select Columns", choices = colnames(iris), multiple = TRUE)
    
  ),
  dashboardBody(
          actionButton("subset_button", "Subset Data"),
          uiOutput("second")
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$subset_button,{
    output$second<-renderUI({
      actionButton("act","action")
    })
    
  })
  
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to stay in basic R you can do an observeEvent which checks for the two inputs wether they change and then just clean the output:

```
observeEvent(list(input$columns_selected,input$columns_selected2),{
    output$second <- NULL
})
```